# Cathode Ray Oscilloscope

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics, electrical-engineering

Is Cathode Ray Oscilloscope (CRO) a device that measures and displays using the electron beam from cathode rays? Are cathode rays its working principle? Does it mean that the line or point showed on CRO screen is the result of electron beam from cathode rays strike on the CRO screen?

Comment: Note that this is obsolete technology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true. You can think of a cathode-ray oscilloscope as an AC voltmeter, where you can actually see the waveforms and measure their peak values and study their shapes.

The oscilloscope responds to very high frequencies because the electron beam that "writes" the waveform onto the screen can move very much faster than any mechanical needle in a moving-coil AC voltmeter.